# The text in pdf file is going out of page

Tags: r-markdown

I am using rmarkdown file and converting the file into a pdf. I installed the necessary packages but whenever i use this command to read from a txt file and converting the file into pdf format.

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r comment='',echo=FALSE}
cat(readLines('DBMS.txt'), sep='\n')
```
````

The result is shown in pdf format but the text crosses the page and the text is not visible with a warning.
What should I do?

[image: This is the pdf file]

Comment: use chunk option `results='asis'`